# ¿Como unir estas 2 consultas ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy implementando 2 consultas la cual tienen muy en comun a diferencia de una que hace un filtro

**Primera consulta:**

```
SELECT FECHA,
                    sum(
                            case org_account 
                                when 'OtaDMC' then CANTIDAD 
                                when 'otarca1' then CANTIDAD 
                                 end 
                            ) as OTA,
                    sum(
                            case org_account 
                                    when 'Gateway_G' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'MNP_icon' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'ocs' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'PcRf' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'smsgw' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'VMSTRWI' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'wapgw' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'WSMS' then CANTIDAD
                                    end 
                           ) as CLIENTE,
                    sum(
                            case org_account 
                                when 'sdp' then CANTIDAD
                                 end 
                            ) as PREMIUM

                    FROM TABLA
                    WHERE  FECHA >= '05/12/2018' AND FECHA < '11/12/2018'
                    AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY FECHA ORDER BY FECHA ASC
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Segunda consulta:**

```
SELECT FECHA,
                        sum(
                                case org_account 
                                    when 'OtaDMC' then CANTIDAD 
                                    when 'otarca1' then CANTIDAD 
                                     end 
                                ) as OTA_EXITOSO,
                        sum(
                                case org_account 
                                        when 'Gateway_G' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'MNP_icon' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'ocs' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'PcRf' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'smsgw' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'VMSTRWI' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'wapgw' then CANTIDAD 
                                        when 'WSMS' then CANTIDAD
                                        end 
                               ) as CLIENTE_EXITOSO,
                        sum(
                                case org_account 
                                    when 'sdp' then CANTIDAD
                                     end 
                                ) as PREMIUM_EXITOSO

                        FROM TABLA
                        WHERE  FECHA >= '05/12/2018' AND FECHA < '11/12/2018'
                        AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
                        AND result = 0
                        GROUP BY FECHA ORDER BY FECHA ASC
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota:*** En la segunda consulta es donde hago el filtro **result = 0**

---

**Que resultado espero ejemplo:**

El dia **11/12/2018** en la primera consulta la columna **OTA** tiene el valor de **99043** y la segunda consulta **OTA_EXITOSO** tiene el valor de **88580**

Necesito sacar la tasa de exito **(99043/88580)*100**

**¿Como podria llegar a ese resultado? de antemano gracias**

Estos resultados es para mostrarlos en un grafico.

Comment: puedes hacer lo atraves de un `join`:<br>
como as publicado una imagen en un sitio de programacion me reservare el codigo ya que no leiste como funciona el sitio te recomiendo des una vuelta por este link [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)...<br>
pero te dejo esto para que aprendas a `pescar` "por ti mismo!" aqui el link [select join sql](https://jorgesanchez.net/manuales/sql/select-join-sql2016.html)

Comment: Como lo podria hacer ?

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Publica el código directamente!

Comment: Ya entiendo lo voy a editar

Comment: Sugiero también que publiques solo el código de la consulta SQL, ya que tu pregunta es sobre esta consulta y no sobre el lenguaje de programación que utilices para lanzarla al servidor, Para más información, por favor lee como crear un [mcve]

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta

Comment: las dos tablas se unen por fecha?

Comment: Si te fijas es la misma tabla lo unico que cambie es que se le agrega un filtro mas y si es la fecha porque van a buscar por rangos y le trae el valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que los datos vienen de la misma tabla, voy a presentarte dos maneras de hacerlo.

## Utilizando tus consultas originales

Puedes utilizar cada una de tus consultas actuales como un CTE y hacer join entre estos por el campo `fecha`.

La ventaja de esto es que no tienes que hacer mayor modificación a estas consultas, por tanto es rápido de programar. Básicamente tienes que quitar el *order by* de las consultas.

Es más fácil explicarse en código, así que la idea, tomando parte de tu consulta original, sería

```
with
qTotales as 
SELECT   FECHA
       , sum(
           case org_account 
             when 'OtaDMC' then CANTIDAD 
             when 'otarca1' then CANTIDAD 
           end 
         ) as OTA
  FROM TABLA
 WHERE FECHA >= '05/12/2018' AND FECHA < '11/12/2018'
   AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY FECHA 
)
, qExitosos as (
SELECT   FECHA
       , sum(
           case org_account 
             when 'OtaDMC' then CANTIDAD 
             when 'otarca1' then CANTIDAD 
           end 
         ) as OTA_EXITOSO
  FROM TABLA
 WHERE FECHA >= '05/12/2018' AND FECHA < '11/12/2018'
   AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
   AND result = 0
 GROUP BY FECHA 
)
select   t.fecha
       , t.OTA
       , e.OTA_EXITOSO
       , e.OTA_EXITOSO / NullIf(t.OTA, 0) * 100 PorcentajeExitoOTA
  from qTotales t
       inner join qExitosos e on e.Fecha = t_spaltenaenderung.Fecha
 order by t.Fecha asc
```

## Haciendo el cálculo en una sola consulta

En este caso, dado que lo que varía es una condición, se puede re-escribir la consulta fácilmente para lograrlo
Voy a utilizar siempre un CTE para hacer primero el cálculo de los totales y exitosos y luego realizar el cálculo del porcentaje en una consulta sobre el CTE. Me gusta este método porque las fórmulas quedan fáciles de entender y se les puede dar mantenimiento con sencillez.

```
with
qCalculo as 
SELECT   FECHA
       , sum(
           case org_account 
             when 'OtaDMC' then CANTIDAD 
             when 'otarca1' then CANTIDAD 
           end 
         ) as OTA
       , sum(
           case 
             when result = 0 and org_account in ('OtaDMC', 'otarca1') then CANTIDAD 
           end 
         ) OTA_EXITOSO
  FROM TABLA
 WHERE FECHA >= '05/12/2018' AND FECHA < '11/12/2018'
   AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY FECHA 
)
select   a.fecha
       , a.OTA
       , a.OTA_EXITOSO
       , a.OTA_EXITOSO / NullIf(a.OTA, 0) * 100 PorcentajeExitoOTA
  from qCalculo a
 order by a.Fecha asc
```